# Dynamic selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do this:

```
var divString = '#sContainer' + [index];
$(divString).append(SSDisplay);
```

So that it is

```
var divString = '#sContainer' + [index];
$('#sContainer0').append(SSDisplay);
$('#sContainer1').append(SSDisplay);
$('#sContainer2').append(SSDisplay);
```

It doesn't seem to be working. I have also tried

```
$('#sContainer' + [index]).append(SSDisplay);
```

Any idea how I can get the jquery selector to do this dynamically?

Comment: It's not working because you're appending an array. What selector are you trying to create, and what is the value of `index`?

Comment: If `index` is just a number you shouldn't put `[ ]` around it.

Comment: Have you tried `$('#sContainer' + index).append()`?

Comment: I'm totally guessing here that your looking for.
`var divString = '#sContainer' + index;`

Comment: thanks just tried it without [ ] in [index], still does not work, even though it should 0,1,2,3,4 - for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are repeatedly appending the *same* `SSDisplay`.

Try:

```
$('#sContainer' + index).append( SSDisplay.clone(true) );
```

Comment: Can you explain in wich way this differ from appending it multiple time?

Comment: @Jaay I am making an assumption that `SSDisplay` is an element (specifically a jQuery object). Appending the *same* element multiple times causes it to be *moved* to its new container. Cloning creates a new copy for each container.